# How to create custom ofstream class for encrypting

Tags: c++, inheritance, ofstream

I'm trying to create custom ofstream class in C++ which allow use like this:

```
RSAKeys keys = LoadRSAKeys("public.pub", "private.priv");

EncryptedOFStream encofstream("outputfile.txt", keys);

encofstream << "Some text";

// Now in outputfile.txt should be encrypted text
```

I have problem with correct inheritance of ofstream class. My brain is damaged after too much of PHP. Could you suggest some basic skeleton?

Comment: Could *you* show what you have tried yet? Note that adding custom classes to the iostream hierarchy is generally not very easy. The hierarchy itself is very complicated, and got many dark corners. Also note that it's probably better to create your own `streambuf`, as those most of the work.

Comment: Why.... why not factor out encryption into a separate module and use ordinary iostreams for I/O? Like `std::cout << enc("Hello World");`?

Comment: Well, I've created custom class with overloaded operator<<: `basic_ostream<char>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char>& os, const MyClass &mc)` but that solves nothing or I just don't know how to get text coming and encrypt it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: well, I should ask my teacher why :(

Comment: @MaxBarnas: The most important thing to learn on StackOverflow is to *always* be honest and upfront about something being homework! Otherwise people will think you are serious and will make serious suggestions.

Comment: My homework was to create encryption class. Using streams are one of requirements. I don't ask for tutorial or doing my homework - I just can't figure this out myself so I am asking for advice/skeleton.

Comment: @MaxBarnas: Advice: Decouple encryption and I/O. Single-responsibility, strong encapsulation, code reuse, etc etc buzz buzz.

Comment: This could be neatly done as a `Filter` component in [boost.iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't get your point.  If the encryption and I/O are already implemented in separate libraries, the class has a single, well-defined responsibility: provide a facade that simplifies the combined task of encryption and I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at projects with similar goals, such as [`zipstream`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/zipstream.aspx) which implements I/O streams for compressing into ZIP and BZ2 archives.  This library uses `zlib` and `bzip2` libraries so it should only include the streams and stream buffers implementation code.

Comment: The code you've suggested does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!